Why is my service not getting started when added depends on, in docker compose file
angulargenerator service is not getting started even when eurekaserver is UP.
services:

  eurekaserver:
    image: clay404/eurekaserver:v1
    container_name: eurekaserver
    ports:
      - "8070:8070"
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl --fail --silent localhost:8070/actuator/health/readiness | grep UP || exit 1"
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
      start_period: 10s
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 700m
    networks:
      - archworker

  angulargenerator:
    image: clay404/angulargenerator:v1
    container_name: angulargenerator
    ports:
      - "9081:9081"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 700m
    depends_on:
      eurekaserver:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - archworker

networks:
  archworker:
    driver: "bridge"

This is returning status UP
curl --fail --silent localhost:8070/actuator/health/readiness | grep UP

if i remove depends on in angulargenerator, both gets started at the same time, which i dont want, i want angulargenerator to wait for eurekaserver to be healthy
This is my properties file of eurekaserver
spring.application.name=eurekaserver

server.port=8070

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/


management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.health.readiness-state.enabled=true
management.health.liveness-state.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true

and properties of angular
spring.application.name=angulargenerator

server.port=9081

eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8070/eureka/

management.info.env.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true

info.app.name=angulargenerator
info.app.description=This is a sample application for generating Angular microservice
info.app.version=1.0.0



try to read logs of angulargenerator service, docker logs angulargenerator

Does docker ps say that your eurekaserver is healthy?

Sorry for late reply, Its showing ( health: starting ) @HansKilian

There are no logs, after running docker logs angulargenerator

'starting' is not healthy. So that's why your other container is never started. You need to figure out why your health check isn't returning exit code 0.

increased my resources to this
deploy:       resources:         limits:           memory: 4048m
stil doesnt work

curl was not installed, now its working, thank you

I found the solution
Curl was not installed in my image so had to install it.
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

MAINTAINER shahbytes.com

# Install curl and wget
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY target/eurekaserver-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar eurekaserver-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","eurekaserver-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]


